# How To Implement A SAAS App In Django Without Using Subdomains

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant, saas

This [article](http://douglastarr.com/avoid-using-subdomains-for-your-saas-app) makes a good argument for avoiding subdomains in a SAAS app. All of the SAAS solutions I've found for Django so far all use subdomains.

Is there a reliable way to implement a multi-tenant app in Django that doesn't use subdomains?

Answer (score 2):

Just build a middleware that sets the tenant and modifies the Request object, based on the URL, and wildcard your URL confs to handle it. Should work fine.